# Azure Devops Organization Code deployment not showing organization

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines

In my azure account, I setup Azure DevOps Organization.
[image: Here is the screenshot of Connected Azure DevOps Organization]

I am trying to deploy code using Deployment Center. Selected Source as 'Azure Repos'. Build Provider as 'Kudu'. Next step, it s required to select Azure DevOps Organization, but it is not showing any organization.

[image: Deployment Center]

Is there anything missing?

Comment: I already have projects in my organization. In DevOps Project, it gives option to create New Project only.

Answer (score 0):

I created three organizations in the Azure DevOps, and followed the same way by using the same account, all the organizations could be found in the deployment center.

[image]

And in the deployment center:

[image]

Comment: I am still not getting the screen. Working with Azure support team to get the issue resolved. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

<strike>**Just create a new organization** in dev.azure.com rather than trying to see the default one and it will be displayed in portal.azure.com.</strike>

I don't know why but this worked for me. It must be a bug as discussed here and it seems like it remains unsolved: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/276647/azure-app-services-deployment-center-not-finding-m.html

**Edit:** I've just realized that I was trying to use Azure Repos with the organizations including only the projects using TFVC. Azure Repos works with only Git repositories so you must be sure that you are trying the appropriate combinations.